# Some trouble with open/closed set

Tags: calculus

I'm just confused about a perhaps trivial problem to the math community. I learned, and I can understand, that set $A=\{(-1)^n\}$ is a closed set, with two limit points at -1 and 1. The set is closed and the limit points are in $A$. The set $B:=\{(-1)^n+\frac{2}{n}\}$ has - to my opinion - the same limit points at -1 and 1.

I found in a book entry the hint, that $B$ is closed, too. But, to my opinion, the limit points are not in $B$ now. So, when the definition for closed sets say, that it should contain all its limit points, why is $B$ closed?

Has anyone any idea?

Comment: It turns out that $B$ is *not* closed, for the reason that you have mentioned.

Comment: Note that $A$ has two limit points when viewed as a sequence, but not when viewed as a set. $A$ is a finite set, so cannot have a limit (aka accumulation) point. (Which shows it is closed.) $B$ is an infinite set, or viewed as a sequence, is a sequence with an infinite image.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate all your answers :) $A$ was a sequence, sorry for the error in coding, it should be, I assume: $A=\{(-1)^n\vert n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $B$ the same. And with your answers I regard $B$ as not closed.

Comment: That notation is still set notation.

Comment: A set $X$ is closed if every limit point of $X$ is a point of $X$. The set $\{-1,1\}$ is closed because it does not have any limit points, and so it is vacuously true that every limit point of $\{-1,1\}$ is a point of $\{-1,1\}$. The set $S=\{(-1)^n+\frac{2}{n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is not closed because $-1$ is a limit point of $S$, but $-1\not\in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed $B$ is not closed. A set is closed if its complement is open. The complement of $B$ contains the point $-1$ but not open neighbourhood of $-1$.

Note that your statement that $B$ doesn’t contain the limit points in the plural is wrong – it does contain $(-1)^2+\frac21=1$.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. $A$ It is still in set notation ($a_n:=(-1)^n$) is maybe better. And, yes, 1 is in $B$. I'm sorry for my inexactness (and sorry for my English :))